# npm install vs-tac exits with err code 1

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I wanted to install vs-tac with npm with the command

> npm install -g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 1
>   4.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac"

but i get a lot of warnings and npm exits with err code 1 here the output: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTiH.png)

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 or are you running with a standalone installation of a Tools for Apache Cordova CTP?

Comment: i installed vs 2015 and selected the whole mobile-section ..

Comment: Try installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, which installs TACO Update 5, and then install the new TACO Update 6. That should mean you don't need to use the npm.